# how to arrange this code in alphabetically arrange

Tags: php, jquery

how to arrange this in alphabetically arrange help me pls thanks in advance

```
<?php
    $result = getcaseList("Anaphylaxis");
?>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="emergency">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    foreach($result as $case_data)
    {
?>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $case_data['case_id'];?>">
<?php echo $case_data['case_name'];?><br />
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse<?php echo $case_data['case_id'];?>" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <h4></h4> <?php echo $case_data['case_description'];?>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4></h4><?php echo $case_data['case_causes'];?>
            </div>
```

im newbie in php

Comment: this depends upon how how made your mysql query?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to sort. Would it be the `foreach` output?

Comment: I assume you want to sort the results of **the query you have not shown us** So **show us the query** Remember we are not **clairvoyant** and we are not **looking over your shoulder**

Comment: <?php
include 'function.php';

function getcaseList($case_name)
{
 $query = "SELECT case_id, case_name, case_description, case_causes FROM tbl_case"; //WHERE case_name= :case_name
 //$dataArray = array(':case_name'=> $case_name);
 $result = QuerySelect('all', $query, '');
 return $result;
}

Answer (score 1):

Well ,As per my understanding you want all your data in alphabetical order in `div` but that is possible only when you fetch your records in alphabetical order.
For example::

`select * from users order by firstname ASC`

This will fetch all users in alphabetically ascending order depending upon firstname of the user.

Comment: Whats this +1 for a reasonable guess?

Comment: I think he may be trying to explain expected result using above example

Comment: <?php
include 'function.php';

function getcaseList($case_name)
{
 $query = "SELECT case_id, case_name, case_description, case_causes FROM tbl_case"; //WHERE case_name= :case_name
 //$dataArray = array(':case_name'=> $case_name);
 $result = QuerySelect('all', $query, '');
 return $result;
}